# Notepad ++ highlights everything that comes after <%= in html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notepad++, erb, scintilla

[image]

See the image above. 
I'm working on notepad ++.
html.erb files are presented that way, and I don't know how to get rid of the sky blue highlighting that follows <%=.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is the commented out end tag on that line.  The `%>` is being commented out.  Try using `"` instead of `'` for your strings.

Comment: +1, the HTML lexer for Notepad++ (probably in most scintilla based apps) is seeing the <% as an ASP/VB block of code, and in VB/VBS, ' is a comment

Answer (score 8):

zsalzbank, Ben and peterjwest are all correct. Here's some new information:

SciTE 2.29 has a version of `SciLexer.dll` that doesn't crash Notepad++ 5.9.3 and also interprets the single quote correctly.

I downloaded it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scintilla/files/SciTE/2.29/ - the file you need is `wscite229.zip`

You can copy the new `SciLexer.dll` from the SciTE download into the Notepad++ folder.

UPDATE: Full instructions here: http://blog.dominicsayers.com/how-to-edit-erb-files-using-notepad/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good article on it: http://therubyway.wordpress.com/2008/11/23/rails-on-notepad/

Essentially you just need to replace the scilexer.dll file (downloadable from the link) to fix the bugged `<% %>` syntax highlighting

**Important Update:**

Unfortunately this causes a crash on save (and will empty the file) on the new version of Notepad++, if you really want to use this it may work on an older version such as 5.8, you will have to test this.