# Notepad++ loses HTML tags highlighting after any <% of Mako Templates tag. How to disable this behaviour?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, notepad++, mako, scintilla

Let me attach a picture to explain:

[image]

So after any tag of Mako (`<%block`, `<%include`, ets.) it makes the subsequent HTML code whole sole-colored black. I don't know what to do with this. `Options -> Style Options` adjustments doesn't help.

I've tried to disable `asp` syntax coloring in the `stylers.xml` file by taking `<LexerType name="asp" desc="asp" ext="asp">....</LexerType>` part under the comment. The result I've got is that `asp` has disappeared from  `Options -> Style Options`. But the subsequent code is still black.

As [Mako site says](http://www.makotemplates.org/trac) it is possible to set `lexer.html.mako=1` in `SciTEGlobal.properties`. I did and tried to place that `SciTEGlobal.properties` either into the directory where the `notepad++.exe` lives or into `Application Data\Notepad++` directory. It doesn't help.

How can I set up Notepad++ that it at least considers Mako tags as simple strings in HTML document? Without affecting any other HTML mark-up.

Comment: Although I have a workaround (see answer below) I think this is an interesting situation to try to fix for real. Would you ask for a fix from the Notepad++ team or from the Mako team? `<% %>` is pretty much a standard markup tag, and Mako is breaking that convention. I think the onus is on Mako to fix it, even though it makes more sense for N++ to let the user pass SciTEGlobal.properties. Hopefully one of those teams reads this question someday.

Answer (score 4):

After installing the "Python Script" plugin, append to the file "startup.py" as follows:

```py
# Enable HTML Mako Template Syntax Highlighting
def enableMako(args):
    editor.setProperty('lexer.html.mako', '1')
notepad.callback(enableMako, [NOTIFICATION.READY, NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED])
enableMako({})
```

Default file location:
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\scripts\startup.py

Since the mako option is per-buffer, it has to be activated every time we start looking at one. We do this by registering the callback function "enableMako".

Also, in order for this to take effect as soon as we open Notepad++, we need to set "Initialisation" to "ATSTARTUP" in the following menu:
Plugins -> Python Script -> Configuration

Finally, to automatically apply this syntax highlighting to .mako files, go to Settings -> Style Configurator, select "HTML" from the list of languages, and append mako to the "User ext." field.

Comment: This worked perfectly to fix syntax highlighting for mako templates on Notepad++.

Comment: @SSIgnatzSchönborn can you provide any additional details?

Comment: This solution worked for me, however I needed to **move the `startup.py` script to `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\Plugins\Config\PythonScript\Scripts`**

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I used:

1) I followed the advise of using Python Scripts Plugin (http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/).

2) Wrap "Compare Clear Result Command" in a Python Script called CompareClearResultWrapper.py (code is at the end).

3) Through Plugin Configuration add a MenuItem for the script CompareClearResultWrapper

4) Map the plugin command to shortcut CTRL+ALT+D.

5) There seems to be some problems if you compare the last file in the right view ..

Here is the code of the script CompareClearResultWrapper:

```py
    def clearResultWrapper():
        console.clear()
        console.show()
        for f in notepad.getFiles():
            console.write( "filename, bufferID, index, view = %s\r\n" % str( f ) )
        bufferID_Lang = []
        for view in ( 0, 1 ):
            index = notepad.getCurrentDocIndex( view )
            notepad.activateIndex( view, index )
            fname = notepad.getCurrentFilename()
            bufferID = notepad.getCurrentBufferID()
            langType = notepad.getLangType( bufferID )
            bufferID_Lang.append( ( view, index, bufferID, langType ) )
            console.write( "view, fname, index, bufferID, langType = %s\r\n" % str( ( view, fname, index, bufferID, langType ) ) )
        notepad.runPluginCommand( 'Compare', 'Clear Results' )
        for ( view, index, bufferID, langType ) in bufferID_Lang:
            notepad.setLangType( LANGTYPE.TXT, bufferID )    # RESET
            notepad.setLangType( langType, bufferID )        # Re-Imposta
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix:

1. Ctrl+a
2. Ctrl+c
3. Ctrl+v

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
<% should have %>
```

and try NotePad++ 6.2, Latest version 6.3.3 have a lot bugs

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, SciLexer considers the unmatched `<%` to be a neverending comment. SciLexer has a workaround, but Notepad++ doesn't appear to let you set arbitrary properties for its SciLexer. But I'm so stuck on Notepad++, and this problem makes Mako templates so hard to edit, that I work around it by omitting the `<%` altogether.

Then I bind a function to the TemplateLookup object which renders the `<%` at runtime:

```
template_lookup = TemplateLookup( ... ) # your usual lookup declaration here

# Work around horrible Notepad++ display issue with Mako's <% tags
import types
def generate_mako_tag(lookup, context, tag_body):
  template = Template("<%" + tag_body + "/>")
  template.lookup = lookup
  return template.render_context(context)
template_lookup.tag = types.MethodType(
  generate_mako_tag, template_lookup, TemplateLookup
) # this binds the function to the lookup object
```

In templates provided by that TemplateLookup, instead of

```
<%include file="component.html") />
```

I write

```
<% context.lookup.tag(context, "include file='component.html'") %>
```

It still looks like an ASP comment, but it's closed, so the problem goes away.

It doesn't work with some declarative Mako tags (e.g. `<%page`).

The nested quotes occasionally get annoying. Especially on earlier versions of Notepad++ which has trouble with single quotes, but [there's a patch for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480787/notepad-highlights-everything-that-comes-after-in-html-erb-files).

Comment: This is quite a hack.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Perfect definition of a hack -- the software doesn't do what you want, so you do something it doesn't want you to do. I guess there just aren't enough people affected by this problem for either SciLexer or Mako to fix it. I have a simpler answer also posted here, but sometimes this one is better.

Answer (score 0):

`<!-- %> -->` is a workaround, but is your best friend here. For some reason it took me a while to stumble upon it.

```
<%include file="foo.html" args="bar='baz'" />
```

breaks the formatting below it. But

```
<%include file="foo.html" args="bar='baz'" /> <!-- %> -->
```

leaves the formatting correct. SciLexer considers the unmatched <% to be a neverending page directive, but it seems you can confuse it enough by closing the directive in a comment(!)

I am using Notepad++ v5.3.1.

Answer (score -1):

I am having a similar problem. After using the compare tool, the syntax highlighting disappears. This happens for any file extension. I am mostly working with batch scripts.

I do have a solution to add the coloring back in:
you can right click and go to "Plugin Commands" then to "Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting". This (at least for me) re-does all the coloring for the whole file.

But it is annoying to have to do that after every time you open a file or compare a file or do what you did to cause the loss of coloring.